# How to make a function with multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to take a bit of code that I have and make it into a function that has a name called updateForm with two parameters that are width and height, which will then call a method to draw that rectangle on the canvas. However, I just cannot seem to understand how to use the parameters in order to do that. The JSfiddle for easier viewing. https://jsfiddle.net/pyf10xyL/7/

Thanks!

Here's the function with the parameters

```
function updateForm(width, height) {
   'use strict';
}
```

Here's my code that has global variables but trying to avoid doing it and make it into a function with parameters (the one above)

```
// Drawing the square
   var width = 0,
       height = 0,
       widthValue = document.getElementById('wid'),
       heightValue = document.getElementById('hgt');

      widthValue.value = width;
      heightValue.value = height;

      widthValue.addEventListener("change", function () {
         width = this.value;
      }, false);
      heightValue.addEventListener("change", function () {
         height = this.value;
      }, false);

      function draw() {
         context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         context.rect(0, 0, width, height);
         context.fillStyle = "#EA7B00";
         context.fill();
      }
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? You seem to understand how to give a function multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your goal seems to be to remove these vars from the global scope. You could accomplish this by creating an object that would control the values within itself instead of the window.

## ES6+

```
class Square {
    constructor(h = 0, w = 0){
        // Init the variables.
        this.height = h;
        this.width = w;

        // Add event listeners to the elements.
        const updateHandler = this.updateForm.bind(this);
        ['wid', 'hgt'].forEach(id => {
            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('change', updateHandler);
        });
    }

    updateForm(evt){
        // Extract the information from the event (change).
        // NOTE: I've made the assumption that your target is an input.
        // This evt (event) object may look differently if it's not.
        const { id, value } = evt.target;

        if (id === 'wid') this.width = value;
        else this.height = value;
    }
}

const square = new Square();
```

## ES5

```
function Square(h, w){
    var self = this;
    self.height = h || 0;
    self.width = w || 0;

    updateForm = function(evt){
        // Extract the information from the event (change).
        // NOTE: I've made the assumption that your target is an input.
        // This evt (event) object may look differently if it's not.
        var id = evt.target.id;
        var value = evt.target.value;

        if (id === 'wid') self.width = value;
        else self.height = value;
    }

    // Add event listeners to the elements.
    document.getElementById('wid').addEventListener('change', updateForm);
    document.getElementById('hgt').addEventListener('change', updateForm);

    return self;
}

var square = new Square();
```

Draw function referencing the square object, instead of two global variables.

```
function draw(){
    context.clearReact(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.react(0, 0, square.width, square.height);
    context.fillStyle = '#EA7B00';
    context.fill();
}
```

### Draw()

Your fiddle doesn't run for me, so I'm leaving the draw mostly as your original code. If you asked this question because you intend to draw different squares with different inputs (hence not wanting those int he global space), you can prepare parameters for a function with 'bind'.

```
function draw(targetSquare){
    // logic using targetSquare.height, etc.
}

var square1 = new Square();
document.getElementById('button-1').addEventListener('click', draw.bind(square1));

var square2 = new Square();
document.getElementById('button-2').addEventListener('click', draw.bind(square2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you mean but if you just remove `var width = 0, height = 0` the function will take `width` and `height` from the parameter given.

```
function updateForm(width, height) {

   var widthValue = document.getElementById('wid'),
       heightValue = document.getElementById('hgt'),
       widthValue.value = width,
       heightValue.value = height;

   widthValue.addEventListener("change", function () {
       width = this.value;
   }, false);
   heightValue.addEventListener("change", function () {
       height = this.value;
   }, false);

}

function draw() {

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.rect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.fillStyle = "#EA7B00";
    context.fill();

 }
```